# UIWebView in A UIscrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, scrollview

I'm trying to add a `UIWebView` in a `UIScrollView` in `storyBoard`. I disabled the scrolling for the webView and enabled it for the scrollView . Since there are others views in the scroll view, i don't want to split the parent view.
But my problem is , the webView takes a static height even though I didn't set a height constraint for either of them (the scrollView and webView).
This means that the webView content didn't exceed its canvas(then its extra content got cut) and the scroll view didn't have extra space so it is not scrollable too .

Comment: add some code so that we can understand what you did

Answer (score 0):

What best I understood with your question I am trying to answer.

You have problem that after stopping web view scrolling you are not able to view web view contents. So you can do two things,

1) As your scroll view is having other subviews also,don't stop web view's scrolling but set its frame constrains so that with in a frame size you are able to view all web view content.

2) You can place web view in the bottom of scroll view and according to web view content set scroll view's content size. Set web view's bottom constrain to 0 with its parent so that there is no need to set web view's frame again and again.